# Install Ubuntu on a tablet Asus TF 101 with Android

Tags: software-installation, asus

There is possible to install Ubuntu on a tablet Asus TF101 With Android 4.0.3?
If is possible, which version would be appropriate in my case?
Thanks
Ioan

Answer (score 0):

Try looking on [this](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/?_ga=1.111374596.1835146417.1460906087) Ubuntu page about flashing.